# Numbering Divs using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to number my divs (1, 2, 3...) using javascript.

HTML:

```
<div id="anId(this)" class="nextClass"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function anId(elementthis) {
var newId = 0;
elementthis.setAttribute("id", newId++);
}
```

How can I make this actually work?

Comment: You dont put javascript functions in an id string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap them in a parent div and then use a js script to run down the tree and number the div's.

The code would look something like this:

```js
var app = function() {
  var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper').childNodes;
  var id = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
    if (wrapper[i].nodeName === "DIV") {
      wrapper[i].id = id;
      id += 1;
    }
  }
}();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: Run inspect on the above code and you will see the result you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="index-form" name="LoginForm">
   <div class="index-input" onclick="anId(this)">sdfs
   </div>
   <div class="index-input" onclick="anId(this)">sdfs
   </div>
   <div class="index-input" onclick="anId(this)">sdfsfd
   </div>
   <div class="index-input" onclick="anId(this)">adasd
   </div>
   <div class="index-input" onclick="anId(this)">asdasd
   </div>
</form>
<script>
var newId = 0;
function anId(elementthis) {
 newId=++newId;
 elementthis.setAttribute("id", newId);
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- You would have to make your id variable a global variable else the changes would not be saved in it.
- You would also have to assign the variable in the function to see the consequent increases in the variable for each div.

Comment: but then you would have to click each id for an id to be assigned. Is there any way to number the ids without having to click or trigger anything?

Comment: yes you could call the same function in the onload of the body or you could just define it in the script part as in @Bruno Peres

Answer (score 0):

You can set id of `parent`. and create function to set `id` of each `div` under it. Please try this one:

```js
function setIdChildDivs(id) {
  var newId = 0;
  var d = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id + ' div');
  d.forEach(function(elm) {
    elm.setAttribute("id", newId++);
    elm.innerText += ' (id:' + newId + ')';
  })
}
setIdChildDivs("parent");
```

```html
<form id="parent" class="index-form" name="LoginForm">
  <div class="index-input">sdfs
  </div>
  <div class="index-input">sdfs
  </div>
  <div class="index-input">sdfsfd
  </div>
  <div class="index-input">adasd
  </div>
  <div class="index-input">asdasd
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to go:

```js
let nextId = 1;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.getElementsByClassName('nextClass'), div => {
    div.id = `id-${nextId}`;
    nextId++;
  }
);
```

```html
<div class="nextClass">1</div>
<div class="nextClass">2</div>
```

You can't evaluate Javascript in the `id` attribute so you have to update these ids later.

And also remember that the `id` cannot start with a number.